# One dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

When I run this code on cmd prompt with statement :

```
java Test A
```

output is

```
a
b
c
```

Wasn't it suppose to result in an error since dimension of args is 1 whereas dimension of x is 3 (args=x).

```
class Test
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      String[] x={"a","b","c"};

      args=x;
      for(String i: x)
      {
       System.out.println(i);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Your array has a *length* of 3, the dimension is still 1.

Comment: The enhanced for-each loop uses an iterator for most implementations. And that doesn't require any knowledge about indicies or size, so the compiler is happy to run a for-each over any array/iterable without worry about what is in it. The obvious exception being you can't `for (Object o : null)` or something silly

Answer (score 0):

well, the array variable in java is only a **reference**, so if you give it another reference for a String array it will accept it, so the range of values the array variable(args) accepts is the *references to String arrays at memory*, it's like changing the value of an integer from 1 to 3, it's ok because they're both valid, and in the range that the integer accepts.

Comment: The questioner doesnt understand the difference between the DIMENSION of an array and its LENGTH. Your answer doesnt address that.

Answer (score 0):

It will not result in an error because your object is not final and you are not changing the array object.

here

```java
double[] data = new double[5]{2, 4, 5, 6, 8} // data can change but the instance of the class cant change
double[] data = new double[7] // here you are changing the data but not the object i.e the created instance of the object does not change but the instance the data(the variable) is holding changes
```

I hope you got your answer

Comment: The questioner doesnt understand the difference between the DIMENSION of an array and its LENGTH. Your answer doesnt address that.

Comment: I think he just messed up between Dimension and Length of an array. The rest of the answer is still relevant, I guess.